# jQuery show and hide links scrolling inside a div

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide, show, scrollto

What I have below works. But, I'm sure it's not the proper way to write it. What is the correct way to write this in jQuery to show or hide two different links to scroll through text in a div?

This is a quick explanation of what the following accomplishes.

1. The "wrap" div contains text that overflows itself. This is hidden with overflow hidden in css.
2. The back link is hidden initially.
3. User clicks more and the div scrolls to the bottom of the div, the more link fades out and the back link fades in.
4. The user clicks back and the text in the div scrolls back up, the back link fades out and the more link fades back in.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#scroll-up').click(function(){
        $('#div').animate({scrollTop: $('#div').offset().top}, 1500);
        $("#scroll-up").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#scroll-down").fadeIn("fast");
    });

     $('#scroll-down').click(function(){
        $('#div').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1500);
        $("#scroll-down").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#scroll-up").fadeIn("fast");
    });

});
```

css

```
#outer-wrap { margin-top: -50px; padding: 24px 12px 12px 24px; width: 330px; height: 450px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
#outer-wrap a { display: block; }
#outer-wrap a#scroll-down { display: none; }
#wrap { margin: 12px 0; width: 330px; height: 360px; overflow: hidden; }
```

html

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="scroll-down">Back</a>
     <div id="wrap" class="column first">
         <p>Long paragraph of text.</p>
     </div>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="scroll-up">More</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: hi. i tried your code.its not working.
can you please show in jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7r2Lz/5/ It doesn't seem to work as intended in jsFiddle. It only works partially. It does work in my development environment. Still I really just want to know if the fadein fade out buttons are written correctly. It seems clunky.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fadeIn - fadeOut links are written correctly and working well. However I noticed you are using `.offset()`, you should be aware that this will give you the position of the element relative to the document. So even just adding a margin top or placing the element somewhere else will give you a different value.

Instead of `$('#wrap').offset().top` why not use `$('#wrap')[0].scrollHeight` to scroll down and show the bottommost text. However with this in mind I am also wondering what if the hidden text in $('#wrap') is far more longer than the 360px height you've set. You will just skip some lines of text there and just proceed to the bottom?

Why not go with a simple Show More - Show Less, it will be much easier for a user to read the text. see sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/YKBb9/1/)

Comment: A perfect solution (for me). Thanks.